# Excel function - t-test on an array filtered by either "1" or "2" in Column A

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an array with 2 columns. Column A is "Gender" (either 1 or 2). Column B is "Response" (1 to 5).

I want to do a t-test that compares the male respondents ("1" in Column A) versus the female respondents ("2" in Column A).

I have tried to do this by performing a VLOOKUP on the array, but I can't figure out the formula. This would mean for the t-test I am comparing two filtered versions of the same array (one with male only respondents and the other female).

Comment: How about a pivot table? I think this would be more suitable for a comparison.

Comment: Not sure what statistical parameters do you need, but probably using 'AVERAGEIF', 'SUMIF', 'COUNTIF', 'SUMPRODUCT' would achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just sort the data in Column A and then use the Data Analysis addin to perform a t-test?

Otherwise you could use an array formula 
`{if(a1:a10=1,b1:b10,"")}` to get the male response in an array form and, `{if(a1:a10=2,b1:b10,"")}` to get the female response in an array form.

So putting together with the t.test function `{=T.TEST(IF(A1:A10=1,B1:B10,""),IF(A1:A10=2,B1:B10,""),2,2)}` with the last two parameters ("2" and "2") dependent on the test (directional or non-directional) and the variance of your sample

The "{}" represent an array formula.  To insert an array formula use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER rather than the usual ENTER when finishing the formula

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I use "{=if(a1:a10=1,b1:b10,"")}" as the first array value in a T-Test it returns "invalid". I can't sort the data in Column A because there are more data surrounding these columns that confound the analysis.

Comment: try this {=T.TEST(IF(A1:A10=1,B1:B10,""),IF(A1:A10=2,B1:B10,""),2,2)}

Comment: OK, that computes OK but it just gives a single result (in this case: 0.593103525). How should I interpret that result?

Comment: That depends on your null hypothesis... But from what i remember of the t-test i would say it means that the difference between the responses is not statistically significant.  Try searching for some additional information on the t-test, this is a good resource http://www.vassarstats.net/textbook/index.html